# Docker-compose file (version 2.16.0)

Tags: file, docker-compose, yaml

This is my docker-compose.yml file.

[image]

When I execute the file, I obtain this error:

[image]

Could you please tell me where is the problem?

Many thanks.

I used the following command:

[image]

Comment: please, don't post code as images, post it as text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there is a grammatical error in your file.

it's **version:**, not **Version:**,

you can change your docker-compose.yml file to **version: '2.16.0'**, and `docker-compose up -d` again